# 14ga Wire Out Of 20amp/12ga Circuit (outlet) To Power Smoke Detector

Tags: electrical, wiring, code-compliance, nec

During some renovations I have opened up enough wall for the inspector to note that smoke/CO detectors need to be hardwired throughout the house.
It is much more convenient to power them using the individual circuits I have created than to try to use a whole new circuit and snake it through multiple levels of the house.  The detectors are all wirelessly interconnectable, so they do not need to be on one wire.

As far as the local code concerned, this is allowable. (**907.2.11.5 Interconnection** - Physical interconnection of smoke alarms shall not be required where listed wireless alarms are installed and all alarms sound upon activation of one alarm)

The question:
All the circuits I plan to branch the individual alarms out of are 20amp, 12/2 wired circuits.  I was planning on using 14/2 wire coming out of those, going solely to one smoke/CO detector.  I know that mixing/downsizing gauges in a branch is typically a no-go, but it seems like this isn't hitting the issues one typically has doing so.
Any commentary, especially regarding NEC 2017/2020 code sections prohibiting this specific scenario would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can't run undersized wire between boxes. Period.

Comment: If using 14/2 use 15 amp breaker/s.  Quite sure the alarms won't use even 15 amps.

Comment: Looks like i'll be using 12/2 wire for those detectors then, what an unfortunate lack of situational exception in the code, eh.

Comment: If keeping 20 amp breaker must use 12/2 for whole circuit.  14/2 is big no-no and can cause you to be denied any and all insurance claims and inspector will make you rip it out.

Comment: I thought you could mix and match 12 and 14 IF (and that's the big IF), the breaker for the circuit was downsized to 15 amps and the wiring labeled in the main panel that part of the circuit was 14ga.

Comment: I'm hoping future code iterations will see how nonsensical this approach is when applied to lights/smoke detectors.  I'm not downsizing my outlets to 15amp just so a fixed appliance that could never see/draw even a 10th of that (smoke detectors) can be deemed legal, that's even less logical.  Much appreciate the comment, 12ga wire for the smoke detectors it shall be.

Comment: Isherwood had it right, but for perspective, try not to think about the device attached, but the proverbial 'weakest link' in the chain. If your run of 14g wire has a nail through it (or any other fault), then the breaker will cheerfully pump 20A until it trips itself, by which time you might already have a fire.

Comment: @crip659: I know this is off topic, but insurance companies cannot deny claims so easily. They can drop your coverage going forward if they find out about it, but "homeowner did something stupid or illegal" is a risk they have to take on to be licensed to sell insurance.

Comment: @whatsisname  Insurance will try to keep your money by almost any legal(you hope) means possible.  They are not your friend.  They live for the fine print.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the future:

- 12/2 20A initially
- You add a branch 14/2 to a smoke detector
- Next owner decides they want a light in the ceiling near the smoke detector and adds an LED fixture (in theory, no worse than the smoke detector - very low current)
- The owner after that decides they want a convenience receptacle for charging phones, etc. (also low current, but now a true 15A duplex receptacle instead of hardwired device) and puts a branch down the wall and installs the receptacle.
- HVAC goes out in the winter. Owner's relative (we'll pretend owner strictly knows "only use this receptacle for small stuff") plugs in a typical 1500 W heater and some other stuff.
- Circuit runs for hours at ~ 20A. Overheats that 14/2 weakest link **without tripping the 20A breaker.**

Where there is likely an exception is that an appliance *with factory installed wire* can have smaller wire (14, possibly even smaller!) because that wire is guaranteed to only serve that device. But that doesn't work for other wires.

Comment: Ah shucks.  Yeah.  That does make sense. Well, off i go rewiring some lights i had on 14/2 as well.  Thanks Manassehkatz.  Logic does prevail.

Answer (score 2):

### Breakers protect wires

And that's the *only* function it has, on a branch circuit with multiple small loads and receptacles. Since really, the appliances are too small to reliably be protected. A 20A breaker won't protect a smoke detector from destruction.

Honestly, this is fairly obvious when you think about it.   How did you miss it? Cognitive bias.  You are searching for and noticing rules and logic that *support* your goal, and disregarding what *does not support* your goal.  You may be at risk of this happening elsewhere in your electrical decisions. That's important a) for safety and b) so you don't get blind-sided at inspection time.

Comment: Yeah, it is easy to get carried away with looking to validate ones goals, but this is why I ask the question.  It does still peeve me that one is left responsible for various future home owners decisions, but I do like erring on the side of caution, so it's certainly better this way.   I now have blisters from re-wiring/wire nutting 12/2 wire in dozens of recessed lights (properly, so the wire is twisted outside the nut) and look forward to doing the same for the smoke detectors.

Comment: Oh, you don't need to twist the wires outside the nut.  In fact, *I wouldn't*.  I just get all the wires squared off and close enough to all make it into the "funnel".  At that point, once you start twisting, the wire nut WILL twist them together tightly, regardless of how they were shaped before.  If not, you're not tightening nearly enough. A 20A breaker is incapable of protecting #14 wire *today* nevermind the future.

Comment: Yup, squared off for sure, I was also told to keep twisting the nut until i saw the wires outside of it start to twist together as well, indicating that they are good n tight in there.  Logic being that when they heat up/cool down during usage cycles, they tend to work themselves loose and the extra twist helps keep em tight

Answer (score 1):

You asked for NEC reference. Section 240 is kind of a mess.

> NEC 240.4 Protection of Conductors. Conductors, other than flexible
> cords, flexible cables, and fixture wires, shall be protected against
> overcurrent in accordance with their ampacities specified in 310.14,
> unless otherwise permitted or required in 240.4 (A) through (G).

So 310.14 applies unless (A) through (G) requires otherwise. I move through (A) through (C), which don't have provisions that apply, to:

> 240.4(D) Small Conductors. Unless specifically permitted in
> 240.4(E) or (G), the overcurrent protection shall not exceed that required by (D)(1) through (D)(7) after any correction factors for
> ambient temperature and number of conductors have been applied.

Many people skip to 240.4(D)(4) which limits #14 copper to 15A, but that skips right over (E), which (D) gives priority to.

> 240.4(E) Tap Conductors. Tap conductors shall be permitted...(1)210.19(A)(3) and (A)(4)...other loads.
>
> 210.19(A)(4) Other Loads. Branch circuit conductors...shall have an ampacity sufficient for the loads served and shall not be less than 14
> AWG.

So 310.14 applies, which in turn table 310.16 is applicable. If using NM cable section 334.80 limits NM cable to the 60°C column, so you can't exceed 15A with #14 NM cable.

Comment: Right. The tap rules show that NEC *did in fact contemplate* what OP thinks they neglected unfairly.  They contemplated it, and rejected it in residential applications like this.